# Flexbox width of header aligned with outer part of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to align my content blocks in the middle of the page, now i'm willing to align the header with the outer content blocks

In the image you can see what needs to happen

This is my current result:

[image]

And this is how it need's to look like
[image]

So when scaling the browser the content is going to the first line if there is space, the header needs to grow with this at that moment.

Here is a codepen with the flexbox in it

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Dirkandries/pen/XmpGzw

Is this possible without using media queries and **keeping the content boxes the same size**?

*The padding and margin can be removed

Comment: No margin and justify-content: space-between? Does this do your trick?

Comment: No, I need the space around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no solution to your question using only CSS and the flex box model.

If what you want is just to align the background of the header, you can fake it.

You need another flex container, that will give you a background with the same rules as the real one. (And that will be used only for this... not really semantic)

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 170px;
  text-align: center;
}
section{
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.headerbkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.headerbkg div {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<article class="flex">
  <header>
    Header needs to be alignd with the container outer part
  </header>
  <div class="headerbkg">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
  </div>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
</article>
```

The real header is given a margin that will keep it always narrower that the background, so that won't spoli the effect.

To make this less evident, I have given it a centered text

Answer (score 7):

**Challenge #1**

In looking at your code, you have a 10px margin applied to each box:

```
section {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

So one problem you will encounter in trying to align the header edges with the box edges is that there's an additional 10px of transparent space beyond the border of each box. But you're asking for the header to align with the *border* of the box. So we can either remove the margin from each box, or adjust the width of the header. I've gone with the latter in my solution below.

**Challenge #2**

You've specified a fixed width for each box (300px). This makes it difficult to match the header width with the row of boxes. What happens when the screen is 750px or 1150px wide? The boxes don't stretch to fill the width, a gap is created as a result, and the box row doesn't align with the header.

*The box row width is 960px but the header width is 1150px.*

[image]

---

#### One possible solution (or step in the right direction)

- Align the flexbox in a `column` direction to vertically stack the header and the boxes (which are wrapped in a new container)
- Use a **nested flexbox** to align the boxes in a row
- Use [**`calc`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) for width values
- Use **media queries** for screen adjustments

**HTML**

```
<article class="flex">
    <header>
        Header needs to be alignd with the container outer part
    </header>
    <div id="nested-inner-container"><!-- new container for nested flexbox -->
        <section>content</section>
        <section>content</section>
        <section>content</section>
        <section>content</section>
        <section>content</section>
        <section>content</section>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
body {  margin: 0; }

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* main groups (header and div) in column direction */
    align-items: center;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /* width accounts for left and right box margins */
    background-color: blue;  
}

#nested-inner-container {
    display: flex; /* box group (flex item) becomes flex container, as well */
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%; /* width equal to header width */
}

section {
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px); /* flex basis equals four boxes per row less margins */
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  section { flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 60px); } /* three boxes per row less margins */
}    
@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  section { flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px); } /* two boxes per row less margins */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  section { flex-basis: calc(100% - 20px); } /* one box per row less margins */
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKgVYb

*NOTE: This answer may or may not be exactly what you're looking for. The question didn't address all the details (like "can the margins be adjusted?", "are the box widths adjustable?", "are media queries not an option or just something you're hoping to avoid?"). So my goal in this answer was to offer up some concepts that hopefully get you where you want to go. AT A MINIMUM, the header and the boxes align in all screen sizes :-)*

Comment: I do like your answer but it's not really where i'm looking for, like you are already saying. The width of the content boxes needs to stay the same all the time

Answer (score 1):

The following are my adressment of the question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"
        >

        <link href = "CSS/Example.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css"
        >
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            Header needs to be alignd with the container outer part
        </header>

        <div class="flex">
            <section>content</section>
            <section>content</section>
            <section>content</section>
            <section>content</section>
            <section>content</section>
            <section>content</section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,
*
{
    border     : 0;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}

.flex
{
    display         : flex;
    flex-wrap       : wrap;
    justify-content : center;
}

header
{
    background : blue;
    display    : block;
    height     : 50px;
    margin     : auto;
    width      : 300px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 620px)
{
    body header
    {
        width : 620px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 940px)
{
    body header
    {
        width : 940px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1260px)
{
    body header
    {
        width : 1260px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1580px)
{
    body header
    {
        width : 1580px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1900px)
{
    body header
    {
        width : 1900px;
    }
}

section
{
    background : red;
    display : block;
    width      : 300px;
    height     : 200px;
    margin     : 10px;
}
```

Firstly, in the CSS file there is the segment...

```
*
{
    border     : 0;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}
```

By setting `border`, `margin` and `padding` to `0` for all elements you can eliminate any default settings for those properties that some or all browsers might display for an element.  By adding `box-sizing : border-box;` any `border` or `padding` settings you make will be contained within the `width` of an element rather than without, making laying out a page much simpler.

I tend to include this snippet as a precaution.

As for setting the width of your `header`, it will need to be set to a fixed width that will need to be changed whenever the concentration of `section`'s (themselves of a fixed width) to a line changes, which will occur whenever the viewport reaches certain widths.

The width of the header, and the width of the viewport at which it is changed, will equal the total width of the sections in one full line plus the total width of the margins between them, nnamely 300px, 620px, 940px, 1260px, 1580px, and 1900px.  I have used media queries to perform the changeover at those points.

Note : Because of specificity issues caused when seeking to override a property using media queries I have placed `body` in front of the definition of `header` in each of the media queries.

Since the width of `header` isn't flexible and `flex` is mainly there to distribute the `section`'s, I have placed `header` outside of `flex`.

If you have any questions or comments about my answer, then please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier then it looks. Here is the CodePen: http://codepen.io/mikestratton/pen/PPmpKQ

Add the following two classes to your CSS:

```
.sleft {
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.sright{
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

Then change your HTML to:

```
<article class="flex">
  <header>
    Header needs to be alignd with the container outer part
  </header>
  <section class="sleft">content</section>
  <section class="sright">content</section>
  <section class="sleft">content</section>
  <section class="sright">content</section>
  <section class="sleft">content</section>
  <section class="sright">content</section>
</article>
```

Comment: I'm willing to keep the content boxes the same size, so when 3 of them will fit in on 1 line you will get 3 of them and combined with a space around

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking for. You displayed the correct image as having two content boxes aligned in each row to the header. If you are asking for 3 content boxes per row I can do this.

Comment: Also, do you have desired width (Fluid or Defined) to perform this? You can use 100% or set it in pixels, 900px for example.

Comment: the header needs to be 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Its Not the same as you want but i tried to do some little hacks & tweeks

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpEdKq

Check is this ok or you can use  grids instead and it will be responsive too, Sorry if it doesn't help you Thanks

Html Code:

```
<article class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    Header needs to be alignd with the container outer part
  </header>


  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  </div>
</article>
```

css code:

```
    body{
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{width:80%; margin-left:10%;margin-right:15%;}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
}
header{

  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
section{
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;

}
```